# Hangman program w/ Python and JSON

Tags: python, json, hangman

What improvements can I make? Should I organize my functions based on A-Z? For example, **f**ind_letter function comes before **g**uessing function.

```
import json
import random
import re


def find_letter(user_input, vocab, i=None):
    return [i.start() for i in re.finditer(user_input, vocab)]


def guessing(tries,vocab,blank_line):
    while tries > 0:
        user_input = input("Guess:")

        if user_input in vocab:
            if not(user_input in blank_line):
                index = find_letter(user_input=user_input,vocab=vocab)
                i = 0
                while i < len(index):
                    blank_line[index[i]] = user_input
                    i += 1

                if not('_' in blank_line):
                    return "you won!!!"
            else:
                print("YOU ALREADY TRIED THAT LETTER!")
        else:
            tries -= 1

        print(str(blank_line) + "  Number of Tries : " + str(tries))

    return "you lost"


def hangman_game(vocab):
    'Preliminary Conditions'
    print(introductory(vocab=vocab))
    tries = num_of_tries(vocab=vocab)
    blank_line = produce_blank_lines(vocab=vocab)
    print(blank_line)

    print(guessing(tries=tries,vocab=vocab,blank_line=blank_line))


def introductory(vocab):
    return "HANGMAN GAME. So...what you gotta do is guess and infer what the word might be. " \
           "WORD COUNT : " + str(len(vocab))


def num_of_tries(vocab):
    if len(vocab) < 7:
        return 8
    elif 7 <= len(vocab) < 10:
        return 10
    else:
        return 14


def produce_blank_lines(vocab):
    blank_line = []
    for i in vocab:
        if i.isalpha():
            blank_line += "_"
        elif i == " ":
            blank_line += " "
        else:
            blank_line += i + " "

    return blank_line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = json.load(open("vocabulary.json"))
    vocab = random.choice(list(data.keys())).lower()
    print(vocab)
    print(hangman_game(vocab=vocab))
```

Snippet of the JSON File

```
{"abandoned industrial site": ["Site that cannot be used for any purpose, being contaminated by pollutants."], "abandoned vehicle": ["A vehicle that has been discarded in the environment, urban or otherwise, often found wrecked, destroyed, damaged or with a major component part stolen or missing."], "abiotic factor": ["Physical, chemical and other non-living environmental factor."], "access road": ["Any street or narrow stretch of paved surface that leads to a specific destination, such as a main highway."], "access to the sea": ["The ability to bring goods to and from a port that is able to harbor sea faring vessels."], "accident": ["An unexpected, unfortunate mishap, failure or loss with the potential for harming human life, property or the environment.", "An event that happens suddenly or by chance without an apparent cause."], "accumulator": ["A rechargeable device for storing electrical energy in the form of chemical energy, consisting of one or more separate secondary cells.\\n(Source: CED)"], "acidification": ["Addition of an acid to a solution until the pH falls below 7."], "acidity": ["The state of being acid that is of being capable of transferring a hydrogen ion in solution."], "acidity degree": ["The amount of acid present in a solution, often expressed in terms of pH."], "acid rain": ["Rain having a pH less than 5.6."]
```

Comment: @ close-voter: Answers on this site are *always* "opinion-based." I don't even know why that's a close-vote reason. Anyway, this question is fine. Also to answer the OP's one explicit question: Almost certainly you should *not* arrange these six functions in a-z order. :)

Comment: Please include an example (even tiny no problem) json file for easier testing. (The question is fine upvote from me)

Comment: @Quuxplusone How do programmers organize functions then?

Comment: @Caridorc Sure. I added a snippet of the JSON file because the JSON file I downloaded is too big.

Comment: @austingae _How do programmers organize functions then?_ Typically by topic, and fine-grained enough that the order doesn't matter. For example you might put everything related to Hangman in `hangman.py`; or once that gets too big, you'd put everything related to the user interface in `hangman-ui.py` and everything related to core gameplay in `hangman-core.py`; or once that gets too big, you'd split out `hangman-dictionary.py` into its own file... And then sure, I'd probably sort those _files_ alphabetically in my manifest or Makefile or whatever.

Comment: It occurs to me that sorting functions by name has the [dictionary problem](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-look-for-a-word-in-the-dictionary-if-you-dont-know-how-its-spelled): I can't find the function (say, `introductory()`) unless I already know how to spell it! And if I know how to spell it (say, my IDE has a sidebar index of all the functions in the current file) then I likely don't care where in the file it is (since I can jump there using my IDE). But everyone has an "IDE" for the filesystem (`ls`), and the filenames themselves make a rough "index by topic" — dictionary problem solved!

Comment: I see...organize by similarities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = json.load(open("vocabulary.json"))
```

Unless Python 3 has changed this, I think you're leaking the open file handle here. What you want is more like

```
with open("vocabulary.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

which IMHO is even a bit easier to read because it breaks up the mass of nested parentheses.

```
vocab = random.choice(list(data.keys())).lower()
```

Same deal with the nested parentheses here. We can save one pair by eliminating the unnecessary materialization into a `list`. [EDIT: Graipher points out that my suggestion works only in Python 2. Oops!]

Also, `vocab` (short for *vocabulary*, a set of words) isn't really what this variable represents. `data.keys()` is our *vocabulary*; what we're computing on this particular line is a single *vocabulary word*. So:

```
word = random.choice(data.keys()).lower()
print(word)
print(hangman_game(word))
```

I can tell you're using Python 3 because of the ugly parentheses on these `print`s. ;) But what's this? Function `hangman_game` doesn't contain any `return` statements! So it basically returns `None`. Why would we want to print `None` to the screen? We shouldn't be *printing* the result of `hangman_game`; we should just call it and discard the `None` result.

```
word = random.choice(data.keys()).lower()
print(word)
hangman_game(word)
```

---

```
def hangman_game(vocab):
```

Same comment about `vocab` versus `word` here.

```
'Preliminary Conditions'
```

This looks like you maybe forgot a `print`? Or maybe you're trying to make a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)? But single quotes don't make a docstring AFAIK, and even if they did, "Preliminary Conditions" is not a useful comment. I'd just delete this useless line.

```
print(introductory(vocab=vocab))
```

In all of these function calls, you don't need to write the argument's name twice. It's a very common convention that if you're calling a function with only one argument, the argument you pass it is precisely the argument it needs. ;) Also, even if the function takes multiple parameters, the reader will generally expect that you pass it the right number of arguments *in the right order*. You don't have to keyword-argument-ize each one of them unless you're doing something tricky that needs calling out. So:

```
print(introductory(word))
```

And then you can inline `introductory` since it's only ever used in this one place and it's a one-liner already:

```
print(
    "HANGMAN GAME. So...what you gotta do is guess and infer what the word might be. "
    "WORD COUNT : " + str(len(vocab))
)
```

Personally, I would avoid stringifying and string-concatenation in Python, and write simply

```
print(
    "HANGMAN GAME. So...what you gotta do is guess and infer what the word might be. "
    "WORD COUNT : %d" % len(vocab)
)
```

I know plenty of working programmers who would write

```
print(
    "HANGMAN GAME. So...what you gotta do is guess and infer what the word might be. "
    "WORD COUNT : {}".format(len(vocab))
)
```

instead. (I find that version needlessly verbose, but it's definitely a popular alternative.)

```
tries = num_of_tries(vocab=vocab)
blank_line = produce_blank_lines(vocab=vocab)
print(blank_line)
print(guessing(tries=tries,vocab=vocab,blank_line=blank_line))
```

It's odd that you abbreviated `number_of_tries` to `num_...`, but then left in the word `of`. I would expect either `number_of_tries` or `num_tries` (or `ntries` for the C programmers in the audience); `num_of_tries` is in a weird no-man's-land.

It's weird that you have a function named `produce_blank_lines` that produces actually a *single* `blank_line`. It's even weirder that the value of `blank_line` is not a constant `"\n"`! This suggests that everything here is misnamed. You probably meant `underscores = produce_underscores(word)` or even `blanks = shape_of(word)`.

Finally, it is weird that `blank_line` is not even a string, but rather a `list` of characters.

I would replace this entire dance with something like

```
blanks = ''.join('_' if c.isalpha() else ch for ch in word)
```

or

```
blanks = re.sub('[A-Za-z]', '_', word)
```

This would lose your addition of a blank space after each non-space-non-alpha character, but IMHO that's actually an *improvement* over your version. (Your sample JSON doesn't show any examples of words containing non-space-non-alpha characters. My version certainly performs better for words like `non-space` or `Route 66`.)

---

```
if not(user_input in blank_line):
```

This would be idiomatically expressed (both in Python and in English) as

```
if user_input not in blank_line:
```

---

```
index = find_letter(user_input=user_input,vocab=vocab)
i = 0
while i < len(index):
    blank_line[index[i]] = user_input
    i += 1
```

You have another singular/plural problem here (just like with `blank_line[s]`). It doesn't make sense to get the `len` of a singular `index`. Since the variable actually represents a list of indices, we should *name* it `[list_of_]indices`.

Also, this style of for-loop is very un-Pythonic. In Python we can say simply

```
for i in find_letter(user_input, word):
    blank_line[i] = user_input
```

And then we can inline the single-use `find_letter`:

```
for m in re.finditer(user_input, word):
    blank_line[m.start()] = user_input
```

(Using `m` as the conventional name for a match object.)
And then we can eliminate the regex and just loop over the `word` directly:

```
for i, ch in enumerate(word):
    if ch == user_input:
        blank_line[i] = user_input
```

or

```
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i] == user_input:
        blank_line[i] = user_input
```

In fact, [by not using regexes, we fix a bug](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) in your code: if the chosen vocabulary word contains `.` as one of its non-space-non-alpha characters, a user who enters `.` as their guess will win the game immediately! :D

Anyway, that's enough for one answer, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately your second recommendation produces the error `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing` when trying to randomly choose a key, so the wrapping with `list` is needed. In Python 2 this worked since the keys were a list already.

Comment: But you can get rid of the `.keys()`, `random.choice(list(data))` works.

Comment: And nowadays `f"WORD COUNT : {len(vocab)}"` is all the rage, which is at least shorter again :)

Comment: Ah, I mistakenly thought `random.choice` could handle any iterable. If OP had written `random.choice(list(data))` I probably would have complained that that approach was too "cute" and not expressive enough. ;) The problem of a `random.choice` that works on arbitrary iterables is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581437/python-random-sample-with-a-generator-iterable-iterator

Comment: If I have many variables to concatenate in a string, isn't it better to use +. But if I only have a variable to concatenate at the end of the string, then is it better to use %s or %d?

Comment: The two advantages of `%d` (or `"{}".format`, or `f"{}"`) are that you can format many variables at once, which is handy for [i18n](https://www.mattlayman.com/blog/2015/i18n/); and that they have their own concise DSL for formatting, such as `%02d`, `{:^x}`, etc. Which is easier to write and to read — `"(0x" + hex(p)[2:].zfill(8) + ")"` or `"(0x%08x)" % p`?